# Fusiondirectory and Apache2 interfering with each other

Tags: apache2, dpkg, dependencies

I want to install Dolibarr and it requires LAMP, so I installed it. I get an error and have a wonderful idea of uninstalling everything.

Now, I'm stuck. Every single attempt to `uninstall`/`purge`/`install -f`/`autoremove`, all lead to this:

[image: terminal dump 1]

[image: terminal dump 2]

So in other words, I can't install/uninstall *anything* anymore because there is a prompt that gives priority to the uninstallation of the half-installed `fusiondirectory`, which *can't* be installed/uninstalled because it has a dependency problem with an `apache2` file, which doesn't exist.

This is what I get all the time:

```
Removing fusiondirectory (1.0.8.8-3ubuntu2) ...
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 607: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /etc/init.d/apache2: not found
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "reload" failed.
dpkg: error processing package fusiondirectory (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fusiondirectory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The road I went down, (all the `sudo install apache2`, `install -f`, etc. )

```
echo "exit" | sudo tee /etc/init.d/apache2; ls -la /etc/init.d/apache2

echo "exit" | sudo tee /etc/init.d/apache2; sudo apt purge -y fusiondirectory; sudo rm /etc/init.d/apache2

sudo echo "exit" > /etc/init.d/apache2; sudo apt purge -y fusiondirectory; sudo rm /etc/init.d/apache2
```

I'll keep adding the road I walk down here...

Comment: OK! that solved it....

Comment: echo "exit" | sudo tee /etc/init.d/apache2

ls -la /etc/init.d/apache2

chmod 1770 /etc/init.d/apache2

That was satisfying :)
(that solved it... Charles Green doesn't like sk*ll f*cking ;))